# Trigger if a date from a date field has been selected three times

Tags: apex, trigger

I am creating a trgger that will fire an error when a particular picklist value has been selected three times. This works and the error message displays.

I now need the error to display if a date from a  date field has been selected three times.

I have been told that trigger.old and trigger.new is a way of achieving this, but I am having trouble understanding it completely.

I will provide my trigger so far. Many thanks.

```
trigger FiveAsideQuantityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {

  Integer count =[select count() from Opportunity WHERE Select_Area__c='5-a-side Pitch' AND Start_Time__c!=null];
  for(Opportunity a:trigger.new){
    if(count==3&&a.Area_Of_Hire__c=='5-a-side Pitch'&& a.Start_Time__c=='09:00'){
     a.addError('5-a-side Pitch is fully booked at this time.');
    }
    if(count==3&&a.Area_Of_Hire__c=='5-a-side Pitch'&& a.Start_Time__c=='10:00'){
      a.addError('5-a-side Pitch is fully booked at this time.');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Trigger.oldMap I was able to get the values this same Opp previously had.  I was then able to add the additional check `a.Area_Of_Hire__c  != old.Area_Of_Hire__c` to see if it has changed to this new value.

```
for(Opportunity a:trigger.new){
  Opportunity old;
  if (Trigger.oldMap != null)
    old = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
  if(count == 3 && (old == null || a.Select_Area__c != old.Select_Area__c) && a.Area_Of_Hire__c == '5-a-side Pitch' && a.Start_Time__c == '09:00'){
   a.addError('5-a-side Pitch is fully booked at this time.');
  }
  if(count == 3 && (old == null || a.Select_Area__c != old.Select_Area__c) && a.Area_Of_Hire__c == '5-a-side Pitch' && a.Start_Time__c == '10:00'){
    a.addError('5-a-side Pitch is fully booked at this time.');
  }
}
```

Adding in the `old == null` is only useful if you are running this trigger on **insert** as well as **update**.  If it's only on update you can replace `(old == null || a.Area_Of_Hire__c  != old.Area_Of_Hire__c)` with `a.Area_Of_Hire__c  != old.Area_Of_Hire__c`

Comment: Thanks for this. I am using this for an insert also. When i try to insert I am getting the Error message: Error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, FiveAsideQuantityTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.FiveAsideQuantityTrigger: line 5, column 1: [] (System Code)

Comment: @AndrewHoban What's line 5?  Trigger.oldMap might be null if it's insert.  I never remember the particulars and usually just do trial/error here.  I edited my answer to assume that Trigger.oldMap is null on insert.

Comment: My line 5 is Opportunity old = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id); Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you. The date field I wish to check if it has already been selected is called Date_Of_Hire__c. So where you have put a.Area_Of_Hire__c  != old.Area_Of_Hire__c should I change to Date_Of_Hire__c?

Comment: @AndrewHoban You might be correct, I was trying to line up the checking for changing of a field with your count but I might have actually used the wrong fieldname there.  You potentially need it on both places.  I think I understand your question a little better now... I believe you will need a Count on that other field as well.  Seems like your requirements might actually end up making this a little complex.

Comment: There are no errors in the code but I am not getting the error message I need. I have created 4 different records all with 5-a-side pitch, 09:00 AM and the same date 11/12/2014. On the forth entry the error message should fire. The code you have provided has put me on the right track I think its just something small to change.

Comment: @AndrewHoban Could the issue be between Select_Area__c and Area_Of_Hire__c ?  You seem to have both of those fields checking the same field.  I'm not sure which one you need to be checking.  I think that once you get this part working you are going to need to have your aggregate query take all of that into account at once and then use a map to grab the correct one you need.

Comment: Hmm thank you. I am new to salesforce so this could be tricky. If all of them fields I mentioned previously are selected more than three times an error should appear.

Comment: @AndrewHoban Sorry that I don't have time to fully look into this more, but I'm currently busy at work.  I just tried to give you a simple start that didn't take me too long.